# Root file from server folder in html

Tags: html, href

How do I grab or `href` a file from root folder using this method:

```
../../../pages/development/topic/programing.php
```

I am having some problems using this method, trying to link from to  domain folder(root folder), so used this method.

```
<a href="$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ./pages/development/topic/programing.php" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Read more</a>
```

But this doesn't work, so how do I link a file form root folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly specify the complete address in href of the destination as shown below.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/pages/development/topic/programing.php" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Read more</a>
```

or use this instead

```
<a href='http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/pages/development/topic/programing.php' class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Read more</a>
```

This will also work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can only serve files that are in the Apache directory. You will need to move the file into the Apache directory or use a php script in combination with `include_once`:

```
<?php
  include_once("../../../pages/development/topic/programing.php");
?>
```

Note that this is an insecure approach, especially if you insert variables into the string.